# Finding the list of all subdirectories in a link

Tags: html, subdirectory

Is there any way that I can find all subdirectories for one link? Should I get the permission? For example, in the lecture instructor opened the solutions by entering some keywords after www.site.com/keyword. Now I cannot remember the word, whatever I try, I cannot find, but I know there is a file. That's why I want to see the files, other pages for the link.

Comment: Is this client-side, in JavaScript, or did you have a server-side (php, Ruby, .net etc) language in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find out what resources are available on an HTTP server is to request a resource that tells you. There isn't anything particularly standard about web servers that will provide that, so you'll need to do something specific to the webserver you want the details from.

Note that not all servers will provide something like this.

The closest thing to a standard is that most servers, for a URL that maps on to a directory on their file system, if there isn't an index file in that directory, will generate an HTML document containing a list of links to the resources in that directory.